# Duplicating table rows, but with another value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `product_to_store` (it is `opencart` table), with `product_id` and `store_id` as column headers. Table is filled with data (example below):

```
+------------+----------+
| product_id | store_id |
+------------+----------+
| 123        | 0        |
| 124        | 0        |
| 125        | 0        |
| 126        | 0        |
| 125        | 1        |
+------------+----------+
```

Help (from mysql table dump):

```
CREATE TABLE `product_to_store` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `product_to_store` (`product_id`, `store_id`) VALUES
(123, 0),
(124, 0),
(125, 0),
(126, 0),
(125, 1);

ALTER TABLE `product_to_store`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`store_id`);
```

I would like to duplicate all rows with value 0 as store_id. Instead of value 0, I would like them to have value 1 (for example). How can I do that with using mysql syntax?

So final table should look something like this

```
+------------+----------+
| product_id | store_id |
+------------+----------+
| 123        | 0        |
| 124        | 0        |
| 125        | 0        |
| 126        | 0        |
| 125        | 1        |
| 123        | 1        |
| 124        | 1        |
| 126        | 1        |
+------------+----------+
```

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY. This may be problematic in due course.

Comment: @Strawberry I've edited my question (alter table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
insert ignore into `product_to_store` (
  select a.product_id, 1 as store_id
  from (select distinct product_id from product_to_store where store_id=0) a
)
```

Comment: I sense this could be it. just a sec

Comment: could you explain what each line does? (because i am almost total noob)

Comment: this does exactly what i've said. If you are kind enough to additionally explain I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry for delay with answer. This part selects all PRODUCT_IDs with STORE_ID=0: **select distinct product_id from product_to_store where store_id=0**.
Here we create combination of PRODUCT_IDs from above and some new STORE_ID (in our case it's 1): **select a.product_id, 1 as store_id from ... a**.
And this is for uploading our results into table: **insert ignore into `product_to_store` (...)**. I do not know how else I can clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a cursor to retrieve the records you are looking for. 
Loop through that cursor and put those rows in a record so that you could modify them. 
 
This way you could do something with every line.

For example:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cHelloWorld IS 
            SELECT  product_id, 
                    store_id 
                FROM    product_to_store 
                WHERE   store_id = 0; 

    rHelloWorld     cHelloWorld%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
        --Loop through records from cursor. 
        OPEN cHelloWorld;
        LOOP
                FETCH cHelloWorld INTO rHelloWorld;
                -- Exit loop when all lines have been looked through.
                EXIT WHEN cHelloWorld%NOTFOUND;

        INSERT INTO product_to_store(product_id, store_id)
                VALUES (rHelloWorld.product_id, 1); 
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cHelloWorld;

        COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: this is just too advanced for me. I am noob in mysql :D